# PSL(2, $\mathbb Q$) and elements of infinite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I can't seem to find any literature on PSL(2, $\mathbb Q$). The following is the very second exercise of Serre's *Trees*.

Given any injection $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Q})$ and surjection $g:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then the amalgamation is trivial.

Let $G = \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Q})$ and $A \in G$ is a matrix with infinite order (so determines injection $f$). Using the first exercise of the section, I was able to show that the amalgamated product is isomorphic to $G/\langle\langle~A^2~\rangle \rangle$. So it remains to show that the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $A^2$ is the whole group.

How should I go about proving this?

Comment: $PSL(2,\mathbb{Q}) is a simple group. See either Lang or Artin.

Comment: So that also makes the requirement $f$ is an injection too strict. We just need a map where $2 \not\in \ker f$, right?